# Initializing Dynamic Array of Strings (C++)

Tags: c++

I am working on assignment to create a container class for a dynamic array of strings. I know that it would be much easier/better done with std::vector, but that is not the point. I am having a problem finding the right way to initialize my array in the constructor. The way it is below, I am still being warned by the compiler that the variable lineArray is not used. The program compiles with a warning that lineArray is unused then hangs at runtime.

```
MyBag::MyBag()
{
    nLines = 0;
    std::string lineArray = new std::string[0] ();
}
void MyBag::ResizeArray(int newLength)
{
    std::string *newArray = new std::string[newLength];
    //create new array with new length
    for (int nIndex=0; nIndex < nLines; nIndex++)
    {
        newArray[nIndex] = lineArray[nIndex];
        //copy the old array into the new array
    }
    delete[] lineArray; //delete the old array
    lineArray = newArray; //point the old array to the new array
    nLines = newLength; //set new array size
}
void MyBag::add(std::string line)
{
    ResizeArray(nLines+1); //add one to the array size
    lineArray[nLines] = line; //add the new line to the now extended array
    nLines++;
}
```

http://ideone.com/pxX18m

Comment: Watch out: your `add` function is buggy. After resizing the number of lines has already been incremented by `::Resize`, no need do `nLines++` again.

Comment: I don't know if your "Bag" is just a learning thing or something, but using std::vector< std::string > bag; would be much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a local variable called `lineArray` in your constructor. You want to use your data member, for example:

```
MyBag::MyBag()
{
    nLines = 0;
    lineArray = new std::string[0] ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning to the rescue. Good thing that you had compiler warnings otherwise this would have been a bug which will have taken longer to figure out.

```
std::string lineArray = new std::string[0] ();
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is declaring a **new variable** called `lineArray` with in the constructor. You are not using the class member one. The member `lineArray` pointer will still be pointing to some uninitialized memory.

---

It should be

```
lineArray = new std::string[0] ();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the obvious error reported by compiler (i.e. initializing a local variable rather than assigning to an instance variable) you have a more serious issue: if a value smaller than `nLines` is passed to `ResizeArray`, your code would exhibit undefined behavior by writing data past the end of the allocated region. You need to change the code as follows:

```
void MyBag::ResizeArray(int newLength)
{
    // Add a trivial optimization:
    if (newLength == nLines) {
        // No need to resize - the desired size is already set
        return;
    }
    std::string *newArray = new std::string[newLength];
    //create new array with new length
    for (int nIndex=0; nIndex < nLines && nIndex < newLength ; nIndex++)
    {   //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        newArray[nIndex] = lineArray[nIndex];
        //copy the old array into the new array
    }
    delete[] lineArray; //delete the old array
    lineArray = newArray; //point the old array to the new array
    nLines = newLength; //set new array size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the shadowed member variable, and the `ResizeArray` to smaller array issue, there is a bug in your `add()` method, as indicated by 6602. After your call to `ResizeArray`, `nLines` has already been updated to the new value, so you are actually writing to the wrong array position, and then wrongly incrementing `nLines` again. Make sure to write to the correct position, and there is no need to increment.

```
void MyBag::add(std::string line)
{
    int oldLength = nLines;
    ResizeArray(nLines+1); //add one to the array size
    lineArray[oldLength] = line; //add the new line to the now extended array
}
```